# how can i read a jpg file from desktop

Tags: html

I have a problem with reading images that exist on desktop(jpg format or something else image).
The location is:C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\pozalaptop.jpg. I've try this codes but doesn't work.

```
<img src="C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\pozalaptop.jpg" alt="laptop" width="100"
height="100" /> 

<img src="C:/Users/Marian/Desktop/pozalaptop.jpg" alt="laptop" width="100"
height="100" />
```

Please help!

Comment: use `file:///image_path` protocol may be `file:///C:/Users/Marian/Desktop/pozalaptop.jpg`

Comment: You didn't mentioned the image name.

Comment: If you're hosting a website in your local computer, consider using XAMPP or LAMP, or just Apache instead of just opening html files.

Comment: this is the code?file:///C:/Users/Marian/Desktop/pozalaptop.jpg or "file" must be replace with pozalaptop.jpg?

Comment: hello please watch this link http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/ http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/image-element.htm

Comment: the image name is pozalaptop.jpg

Comment: Girish ai use your code:file:///C:/Users/Marian/Desktop/pozalaptop.jpg but doesn't work

Comment: If you are using xamp, put all your files in one folder in xamp like `htdocs` and give `pozalaptop.jpg` in `src`. If you will give the path as you have given, it will be not visible because browser doesn't have permission to access the file system of the client's machine.

Comment: I know this method Prerak with the file in the same folder in xamp but i just think that is a way to read the file from desktop. it may be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your browser's console to see the error message. If might be a network error, in that case the path can't be found. But more likely is a security exception: Pages which use the protocol `http:` or `https:` aren't allowed to access resources with the `file:` protocol for security reasons (otherwise, attackers could scan your computer for files).

Comment: but how can i dezactivate  this security?

Comment: You can't. If you could do it, then an attacker could do it as well. Also, it wouldn't help much: You could see the image in a browser running on your desktop but no one else in the world could. So mixing HTTP and file protocols doesn't make sense, usually. Find a place where you can upload your image like flickr.com and then use the HTTP URL which they tell you.